# Reformat xml file using xslt and retain exact formatting

Tags: php, xml, xslt, formatting, line-breaks

I have an xml file which needs to be formatted in a specific way to ensure readability.

Source XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facility>
 <attributes>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>Facility Name</name>
   <coordinate>Lat,Long</coordinate>
   <projection>mercator</projection>
   <units>imperial</units>
   <showcart>yes</showcart>
   <shotplanner>yes</shotplanner>
   <sound>on</sound>
   <gfbkgcolor>#ff0000</gfbkgcolor>
   <gftxtcolor>#ffffff</gftxtcolor>
   <gcbkgcolor>#ffffff</gcbkgcolor>
   <gctxtcolor>#000000</gctxtcolor>
 </attributes>
</facility>
```

Expected Output

```xml
<facility name="Facility Name" id="1" 
          coordinate="Lat,Long" projection="mercator" 
          units="imperial" showcart="yes" shotplanner="yes" 
          sound="on" gfbkgcolor="#ff0000" gftxtcolor="#ffffff" 
          gcbkgcolor="#ffffff">
</facility>
```

Ive got a complex xml file but thats pretty much what i'm trying to do.

XSL template

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="facility/attributes">
        <facility id="{id}" name="{name}" 
                  coordinate="{coordinate}">
        </facility>
         <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <test>"hello"</test>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using this `<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>` seems to be throwing an error and does not display the output xml.

1. Is it possible to have line breaks after certain attributes using xsl?
2. Can i have line breaks between children in a given element ( So they could be grouped logically )?

I'm forming the above xml via php. Once i have the xml, i'd like it to be formatted as mentioned above. I can do it using php strings but its a huge file and would be quite tedious to do so. Can xsl be used to solve this problem?

Any pointers on how to achieve this would be much appreciated. Thx

Comment: You need to understand that the processing model of XSLT takes an input tree and transforms it into a result tree which has element nodes with attribute nodes while any formatting of attributes and the space between them is an optional serialization step after the result tree has been created. So line breaks between certain attributes is not something that the XSLT transformation creates, it would be part of the serialization. And the serialization options that XSLT 1.0 defines do not provide any settings for line breaks between attributes.

Comment: So the only way to achieve that output would be to write it out to a file using php with the right formatting?

Comment: To transform the child elements of the `attributes` elements into attributes you can use XSLT elegantly but to enforce a certain formatting of attributes you need to look into serialization options of your XSLT processor or implement the serialization yourself, either in PHP or in XSLT (like http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any XML serializer (XSLT-based or otherwise) that gives you that level of control over the formatting of a set of attributes, though you could probably get close with Saxon by taking advantage of the saxon:attribute-order and saxon:line-length properties on xsl:output: see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters .

It's not clear why your current code is throwing an error, but since you haven't told us what the error is, I won't try to answer that part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Being PHP is a general purpose language and equipped with an XSLT 1.0 processor, you can handle both operations, xml transformation and text formatting, in one script:

**XSLT** Script *(save externally to be loaded below or add as an embedded string with loadXML())*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="attributes/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <!-- Migrate Nodes to Attributes -->
  <xsl:template match="attributes/*">    
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP** Script

```
<?php

// Load the XML source and XSLT file
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('Source.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// Configure the processor
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// Transform XML source
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($doc);

// Add line breaks, tabs, and spaces between attributes to output string
$newXml = str_replace("coordinate", "\n\t\t  coordinate", $newXml);
$newXml = str_replace("units", "\n\t\t  units", $newXml);
$newXml = str_replace("sound", "\n\t\t  sound", $newXml);
$newXml = str_replace("gcbkgcolor", "\n\t\t  gcbkgcolor", $newXml);
$newXml = str_replace("/>", ">\n</facility>", $newXml);

echo $newXml;

// Save output to file
$xmlfile = 'Output.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $newXml);

?>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facility id="1" name="Facility Name" 
          coordinate="Lat,Long" projection="mercator" 
          units="imperial" showcart="yes" shotplanner="yes" 
          sound="on" gfbkgcolor="#ff0000" gftxtcolor="#ffffff" 
          gcbkgcolor="#ffffff" gctxtcolor="#000000">
</facility>
```

Comment: Pretty nice what you did there, I ended up doing it via php since my source is a php array anyways. Posting a snippet of what i did.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php

public function writeToXml(){
  $data = array(
   "id"          => 15,
   "name"        => "Facility Name",
   "coordinate"  => "Lat,lon",
   "projection"  => "mercator",
   "units"       => "imperial",
   "showcart"    => "yes",
   "shotplanner" => "yes",
   "sound"       => "on",
   "gfbkgcolor"  => "#ff0000",
   "gftxtcolor"  => "#ffffff",
   "gcbkgcolor"  => "#ffffff",
   "gctxtcolor"  => "#000000",
   "gbbkgcolor"  => "#0000ff",
   "gbtxtcolor"  => "#ffffff"
  );

    // Inserts a new line with a specified indent
 function insertNewLine($indent = 0){
  $line = "\n";
  $line .= str_repeat("\t", $indent);
  return $line;
 }
    
    // Formats a given string with a trailing space
 function formatString($string) {
  $data = "\"" . $string . "\" ";
  return $data;
 }

 $facility = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
 $facility .= insertNewLine();
 $facility .= "<facility name=" . formatString($data['name']);
 $facility .= "coordinate=" . formatString($data["coordinate"]);
 $facility .= insertNewLine(1);
 $facility .= "projection=" . formatString($data['projection']);
 $facility .= "units=" . formatString($data['units']);
 $facility .= "showcart=" . formatString($data['showcart']);
 $facility .= "shotplanner=" . formatString($data['shotplanner']);
 $facility .= "sound=" . formatString($data['sound']);
 $facility .= insertNewLine(1);
 $facility .= "gfbkgcolor=" . formatString($data['gfbkgcolor']);
 $facility .= "gftxtcolor=" . formatString($data['gftxtcolor']);
 $facility .= insertNewLine(1);
 $facility .= "gcbkgcolor=" . formatString($data['gcbkgcolor']);
 $facility .= "gctxtcolor=" . formatString($data['gctxtcolor']);
 $facility .= "/>";



 $myfile = fopen('application/packages/myfile.txt', 'w+');
 fwrite($myfile, $facility);
 fclose($myfile);
 // echo $facility;
});
```

Comment: Yet another way! But you didn't need to concatenate the XML content since PHP comes with [DOM class methods](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php): `createElement()`, `setAttribute()`, `appendChild()`...